# Is there a way to make Internet Explorer understand this.style.setProperty?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cross-browser

I've started using the excellent D3.js data visualisation library (http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).

The results work great in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. One issue seems to be the heavy use of this.style.setProperty and this.style.removeProperty by D3, which isn't recognised by IE.

I wondered if anyone knew of a workaround or shim or some such? (My JavaScript is pretty poor, BTW).

Comment: Sounds like this would be the type of thing that .attr('propname', 'value') would accomplish in JQuery.   Maybe you could create some typeof wrapper by hacking the definition of setProperty in the d3 library.  JQuery works crossbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting with the same bug you can simply solve it by using the following pattern when you want to change the style.

```
element.style("property", "value");
```

It's absolutely necessary that the value is **always** a string. Otherwise you will get a weird Character Error in IE9 as it can only handle strings.

I tested it with D3JS 3.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

What about .classed('class', true/false)? It works perfectly well in IE9:

```
function mouseOver(d, i) {
    var element = d3.select(this);
    var alreadyHasClass = element.classed('className'); // boolean
    element.classed('cssClass', !alreadyHasClass); // set/remove class
}
```

BTW, it's faster add/remove classes to elements than appending information to "style".

Comment: Nice idea but sadly not in my case. I'm using a data-driven function to transition elements, e.g. positioning. Adding and removing classes won't do this. d3 uses style.setProperty internally to do this.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Because I position my elements (paths, polygons...) based on data and move them after that using transform/translate. It works fine to me in IE9.

Comment: Sorry - should have clarified I am using d3 to manipulate HTML not SVG elements. You can see what I built at [patientstori](http://patientstori.org.uk/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newest version [2.1.3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/archives/master) solves this.  Take a look.

Comment: Thanks for this - tried the newer version but didn't do the trick. To clarify, I am using d3 to scroll HTML elements on the page. Have linked to the current version below in comment.

Comment: The relevant commit is [c2e3735](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/c2e37352ac84eb8b4be89feed90bc2249866f715); I think version 2.0.5. But that only adds support for IE9. I believe the OP is asking about IE8 or below, which is not officially supported. There is, however, [a workaround](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/199#issuecomment-1487129).